# STLink USB communication error when no board is connected

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, st-link

I'm new to using the ST-LINK, and I'm trying to isolate a connection problem, by checking if the ST-Link itself is working well with my computer.

I connected the **ST-LINK V2** by itself to a **Windows 10** laptop.
Nothing is connected to it, bar the USB cable connecting it to the computer.
It's being recognized as  **STM32 STLink** in the device manager.
When I open ***STM32 LS-LINK Utility***, I press connect, and get:

> STLink USB communication error

When I open **ST-LING** -->**Firmware update**, and press ***Device Connect***, I get:

> Communication error with ST-Link. Try to start it.

Which is unclear, considering it has no buttons

Is this sane?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a question about a faulty PC USB port which has been abandoned by the asker

Comment: I'm voting AGAIN to close this question as off-topic because it was a question about a faulty PC USB port which has been abandoned by the asker who is not around to accept their self answer.  We used to wisely call these "too localized"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. There was one USB port that worked.

Comment: You need to accept this so that the question does not keep being churned up for resolution